# Copy/Paste within DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, copy-paste

I am trying to make copy and pasting within a DataGridView to act similarly to Excel. My current code performs this with the exception of the first cell, which seems to be pasting all contents from the clipboard into the first cell. Below is the code I am using on the `cell_keydown` event.

Just to clarify, if I copy the following:

[image: Copied Data]

I get the result:

[image: Pasted Data]

The pasted data, does have a space between the two dates prior to clicking off the cell.

If anyone has a better way to accomplish what I am ultimately trying to do that would be appreciated as well!

```vb
If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
    Dim d As DataObject = dgv1.GetClipboardContent()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(d)
    e.Handled = True

ElseIf e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
    Dim s As String = Clipboard.GetText().Replace(vbCr, " ")
    Dim lines As String() = s.Trim.Split(vbLf)
    Dim row As Integer = dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim col As Integer = dgv1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim linesCount As Integer = lines.Count()

    If (row + linesCount) - dgv1.RowCount > 0 Then dgv1.Rows.Add((row + linesCount) - dgv1.RowCount)

    For Each line As String In lines
        If line.Length > 0 Then
            Dim cells As String() = line.Split(vbTab)
            For i As Integer = 0 To cells.GetLength(0) - 1
                dgv1.CurrentCell.Value = cells(i)
                If col + i < dgv1.ColumnCount Then
                    dgv1(col + i, row).Value = cells(i)
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            row += 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to create methods for the copy/paste routines so you can call them from different places in your code, like on button click, on key press, on menu item click ...etc.

I don't think you have a problem with the `Copy` part since the `GetClipboardContent` function will do the job. As for the `Paste` part, the following code snippet gets the data from the Clipboard and pastes the values of a selection range of cells starting from the CurrentCell. The out of range cells are trimmed.

```vb
Private Sub CopyCells()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(DataGridView1.GetClipboardContent)
End Sub

Private Sub PasteCells()
    Dim s = Clipboard.GetText
    Dim ci = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim ri = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim colCount = DataGridView1.Columns.Count
    Dim rowCount = DataGridView1.Rows.Count

    For Each r In s.Split({ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Dim Cell = ci
        For Each c In r.Split({ControlChars.Tab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            If Cell >= colCount Then Exit For
            DataGridView1(Cell, ri).Value = c
            Cell += 1
        Next
        ri += 1
        If ri >= rowCount Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Call them from the DGV.KeyDown event for example as follows:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.Control Then
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.C
                CopyCells()
                e.Handled = True
            Case Keys.V
                PasteCells()
                e.Handled = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much and for the explanation.