# VB.NET column copy and paste in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, pasting

My problem is pasting copied columns to multiple columns selected with the same values on the datagridview. I have a screenshot of the result I want to execute like one same value copied is to multiple columns.

[image: screenshot]

This is my code in VB:

```
Private sub pasteValues

    Dim clipboardContent As String = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim selectedCells As DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection = Trxn_AwardListDataGridViewX.SelectedCells
    Dim rowCount As Integer = Trxn_AwardListDataGridViewX.Rows.Count
    Dim colCount As Integer = Trxn_AwardListDataGridViewX.Columns.Count

    If Not selectedCells.Count > 0 Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim selectedColumns As New List(Of Integer)()

    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In selectedCells
        If Not selectedColumns.Contains(cell.ColumnIndex) Then
            selectedColumns.Add(cell.ColumnIndex)
        End If
    Next

    Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = selectedCells(0).RowIndex

    Dim rowValues As String() = clipboardContent.Split({ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For i As Integer = 0 To rowValues.Length - 1
        If currentRowIndex >= rowCount Then
            Exit For
        End If

        Dim cellValues As String() = rowValues(i).Split({ControlChars.Tab}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        For j As Integer = 0 To cellValues.Length - 1
            Dim columnIndex As Integer = selectedColumns(j)

            If columnIndex >= colCount Then
                Exit For
            End If

            Dim cellValue As String = cellValues(j)
            Dim decimalValue As Decimal

            If Decimal.TryParse(cellValue, decimalValue) Then
                Trxn_AwardListDataGridViewX(columnIndex, currentRowIndex).Value = decimalValue
            Else
                Trxn_AwardListDataGridViewX(columnIndex, currentRowIndex).Value = cellValue
            End If
        Next

        currentRowIndex += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61349080/14171304